# Cant seem to figure out why the code is going into an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Consider the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './components/Card';
import './App.css';
import Buttongrp from './components/Buttongrp';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [])
  const getData = () => {
    fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => { setDataArray(data) })
  }
  const getSingleData = () => {

    fetch(`https://reqres.in/api/users/${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(datajson => { setEmail(datajson.data.email); setFirstName(datajson.data.first_name); setLastName(datajson.data.last_name) })
  }
  const [cardImgUrl, setCardImgUrl] = useState("https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a0/d5/c9/a0d5c9af2eee2970a6eea591fade8271.jpg")
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("")
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("")

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
  const [dataArray, setDataArray] = useState({})
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container d-flex my-3">
        <div className="display-4 mx-auto d-inline">CV Screener</div>
      </div>
      <div className="container-fluid my-3">
        <Card cardImgUrl={cardImgUrl} firstName={firstName} lastName={lastName} email={email} />
      </div>
      <div className="container d-flex justify-content-center flex-md-row flex-lg-row flex-sm-column flex-xs-column" >
        <div className="d-inline" >
          {
            dataArray?.data && dataArray.data.map((e) => {
              return <Buttongrp id={e.id} getSingleData={getSingleData} />
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and also the component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { FaUserAlt } from 'react-icons/fa';
function Buttongrp(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-light btn-lg mx-2 my-2" onClick={props.getSingleData()}  >
                <FaUserAlt /> Fetched User {props.id}
            </button>
        </>
    )
}

export default Buttongrp
```

The function 'getSingleData' is being called infinitely, till my pc runs out of memory. I have set it to being called only upon clicking the button and yet its still being called even though I didnt click the button even once. I am unable to figure out why this behavior is happening

Comment: Good code indention is **sooo** helpful to people trying to read your question and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
onClick={() => props.getSingleData()}
```

Comment: You are correct that this will solve the problem, but you should include *why* your code solves the problem instead of making people just copy/paste and hope for the best.

Comment: You sure?  Why not just `onClick = props.getSingleData`?  (Aside from the fact that you should avoid using `onClick` handlers in HTML entirely)

Comment: @Tibrogargan this will definitely work, but skipping the arrow function would be better. Where exactly are you coming up with the idea that `onClick` should be avoided??? JSX is not HTML which already hints that maybe your source for that statement is not relevant

Comment: @BrianThompson yeah, not really a JSX dev (comment is correct for `onclick` but not `onClick`).  But I'm thinking that using an anonymous arrow method as a synthetic event might not be the way to go either way,